# Diet tracking android app

Tags: gratis, android, web-apps

I need a software for tracking my calories just like `myfitnesspal`, but myfitnesspal miss many nutritional information on nearly all foods, and it won't let me add say how much Zinc or Vitamin D of a food even when creating a custom food.

- I need an app to track my calorie intake just like `Myfitnesspal`, and with options to add exercise made and calories spent
- Have the option to read bars code and identify the product and have the track all nutrients intake (if possible including omega-3-6-9) fat and protein intake too

For Android and must be free, I don't care if I have to create all my foods I regularly eat

Comment: I'm not using such an app, so I cannot name it – but while waiting for an answer, you might wish to take a look at my list of [Calories Counter](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_weight#group_292)s (which also holds MyFitnessPal). With some luck, the wanted app is there. Fingers crossed!

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you want to track your calories?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [CORN-O-Meter](https://cronometer.com/). It tracks all the food(Including 48 Macronutrients),exercises and as well as  all the biometrics(like sleep,pulse,body glucose,heart rate,blood pressure etc). You can even create custom food with customized micronutrients too.And you can analyse the data as well. Although the android app is not free but the web app is free so you can create a account on the link above and track everything from their..

Answer (score 1):

I do not use Android, but I have found a good [website for tracking (fddb.info)](http://fddb.info).

Very huge database of every possible product. And you can add your own if something is mising.

[And there is a list of Android apps for it.](http://fddb.info/db/i18n/mobile/de_fddb-apps.html)

Page is on german, because I can't find the english one, but I think you will manage that ^^

Comment: Seems good but from what I saw the apps are also in German only and I can't read German :/

Comment: Try to search in play store or google for android apps with fddb

Comment: @mfgmicha I checked out the FDDB website that you recommended. Unfortunately, it is in German for me also. Did you ever find the English translation?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Lose It!](http://loseit.com) for a couple years now and it's awesome to work with.

Also, previously I used the Calorie Counter app from [FatSecret](https://www.fatsecret.com/) which is also very good, just not as feature-rich as LoseIt!

Both of these apps are free to use, though LoseIt does have a premium tier but you don't really get much for the upgrade.

Comment: I just noticed that you are wanting to track down to the individual nutrient level... if that is true, these may not be for you. Confirm with a comment and I will delete this answer.